# Getting a control's non-dependency property's value in VM using MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a WPF application built using MVVM. The control has a text box in which I need to insert tags. The control I am using is **XamT**.

So when user presses insert button, i need to query the focussed control's SelectionStart value,so i can insert the tag at the propert text index.

The selection start property is not a DP, so i cant databind its value and receive change notifications.

I wonder how anyone will do this in MVVM?

The controls is defined as:

```
<x:XamTextEditor Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" 
                 Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  Margin="0 5 0 5" 
                 Template="{StaticResource ResourceKey=MyTextEditorTemplate}" 
                 Name="TBody" 
                 Text="{Binding Body}" 
                 TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                 IsAlwaysInEditMode="{Binding InEditMode,Mode=OneWay}"
                 AcceptsReturn="True" AcceptsTab="True">
    <igEditors:ValueConstraint Nullable="False" MinLength="1"/>
</x:XamTextEditor>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOTE: In this case, unless I had a lot of extra time to spend on this, I would chalk it up to a not-entirely-MVVM-friendly third party control, break the "rules" a bit, and just put some code behind in your View class to pass a reference to that text editor into you view model.

But if you wanted to go "pure no-code-behind MVVM", you would need to create some kind of proxy object that knew how to communicate with the XamTextEditor and also receive events from the underlying view model. This is similar to the mechanism used by Blend/Prism to perform user interaction dialogs: the "action" objects serve as a bridge between the view model (which simply raises an interaction request event) and some other UI elements on the page.

I think the most "robust" way to approach this is to create an object that knows how to "insert a string into a XamTextEditor at the current selection position".

```
<local:XamEditorInserter 
    SourceObject="{Binding InsertTagRequest}" 
    TargetEditor="{Binding ElementName=TBody}" />
```

You could implement this technique in a few ways. The easiest is to define an interface that has an event, which your custom "bridge" object can subscribe to. (`TriggerBase` from the Blend SDK exposes an actual `List<Action>`, which is effectively the same thing but a bit more code to implement):

```
public class CustomTriggerEventArgs : EventArgs
{
  public string StringData
  { 
    get;
    set;
  }
}

public interface ICustomTrigger
{
  event EventHandler<CustomTriggerEventArgs> CustomTriggerRaised;
}

public class CustomTrigger : ICustomTrigger
{
  event EventHandler<CustomTriggerEventArgs> CustomTriggerRaised;
  public void Raise(string s)
  {
    if (this.CustomTriggerRaised != null)
    {
      this.CustomTriggerRaised(this, new CustomTriggerEventArgs { StringData = s });
    }
  }
}
```

Your bridge object would then need to hook up to that event when `SourceObject` was changed:

```
public DependencyObject SourceObject
{
  get
  {
    return this.GetValue(SourceObjectProperty) as DependencyObject;
  }
  set
  {
    if (value is ICustomTrigger)
    {
      ((ICustomTrigger)value).CustomTriggerRaised += this.TriggerRaised;
    }
    this.SetValue(SourceObjectProperty, value);
  }
}

public void TriggerRaised(object sender, CustomTriggerEventArgs e)
{
  if (this.TargetEditor != null)
  {
    var sel = this.TargetObject.SelectionStart;
    var tag = e.StringData;
    // do whatever.
  }
}
```

In your viewmodel, you just define a property of type `ICustomTrigger`, set it to a `new CustomTrigger()`, and call its `Raise()` method when you need to insert a new tag into your text editor.